# Name of data structure that's tree-like with multiple root nodes

Tags: java, data-structures, scala

I'm attempting to implement a data structure, and using a more traditional tree data structure, but I'm not using the root node as it holds no real value in the context I'm using it in.

Ideally, I want to use a structure that is a tree, but that has multiple root nodes (and that is not just a list of trees). Is there a name for a data structure like this?

Comment: Oh yeah? It is not just a list of trees? Why so?

Comment: Hell, maybe it is and I'm simply over-thinking it.

Comment: A set of unconnected trees would be called a [forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29#forest). A list of trees can be a valid implementation of a forest, assuming that no two trees in the list have any node in common.

Comment: If the trees are connected you call it a [multitree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitree).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have one tree with multiple roots, you have a grab bag of separate trees, each with a unique root. In graph theory, a bunch of disconnected trees are called *forest*. But if the trees don't really belong together, it might be more useful to think of it just as a collection (list, map, etc.) of trees.

Comment: A forest... I like that. They are all related, they hold the same type of information, in the same structure. They're basically paths, and some of the paths may have different starting points.

Answer (score 1):

Try for Forest Data structure using Java Programming. I have done this already and it's easy. As Java API contains no general API for trees/graphs, since there is no unique set of features needed in every use case. There are quite some tree/graph-like APIs for special cases, though.And it is easy to make your own graph - one could even say that every object is in fact a node in a graph, with the values of its reference type fields being the (outgoing) neighbors. I had even implemented search using hashing techniques to find the immediate parent and immediate child node, if exists.